# Colocar scroll para baixo

Tags: jquery

Tenho esse jquery que faz a animação do scroll quando clica em um link.

Como faço para que quando clica no link o scroll vai um pouco mais para baixo, tipo um 10% para baixo, teria como?

// Smooth scroll function

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-item a ,  #menu-one-page-menu a ', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"]')) {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')
            || location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top

                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui está um exemplo bem simples, primeiro você selecione o seu elemento `alvo` depois é só realizar uma animação em `body e html` levando o `scroll` até o elemento alvo. Defini um tempo de `600ms` mas pode ser editado. Simples assim!

```js
$('#link').click(function(){
    var alvo = $('#alvo');
   $('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: alvo.offset().top }, 600);
   return false;
})
```

```html
<a id="link"> Clique! </a>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div id="alvo"> target </div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Caso queira, também pode realizar o efeito passando algum valor dentro da função `scrollTop` da seguinte maneira:

```js
$('#clique').click(function(){
  $('body, html').scrollTop(100)

})
```

```html
<a id="clique"> Clique </a>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div>teste</div> 
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div>Outro teste</div> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```